# How to TILE a background image in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

With the absence of VisualBrush in WinRT, I am not sure the approach. Anyone?

Comment: Confirmed, TileMode is not in this version of Metro/XAML

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment I don't believe there is a way, while ImageBrush inherits from TileBrush it's missing the important property TileMode. It's unclear whether this will be included in later versions.

Comment: It's so odd for a TileBrush to not have TileMode.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed there hasn't been much information given in regards to XAML styling WinRT besides
changing Dark and Light themes...

so I guess we have to fiddle and experiment...

While doing some googling on the web I came with the following link... might as well give it a shot...

Creating tiled backgrounds in Metro style XAML apps

http://www.robfe.com/2012/07/creating-tiled-backgrounds-in-metro-style-xaml-apps/

Note that it might work in full screen though I ain't sure on how well it responds to snap and rotation.

Comment: It looks like the link is dead.

Comment: looks like typo it in url. it should be http://www.robfe.com/2012/07/creating-tiled-backgrounds-in-metro-style-xaml-apps/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mindscapehq.com/ now have a TiledBackground control.

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/01/windows-store-app-tiled-background/

`<ms:TileBackground ImageSource="/Assets/debut_dark.png" />`

Requires a license to access the nightly build.