# UWP - How to tile a background image?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, win-universal-app

In a Universal Windows app, I am trying to use a background image (from an ImageSource) and tile it across a control.

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="gridBackground">
  <ContentPresenter />
</Grid>
```

C#

```
void UpdateBackground(ImageSource source)
{
// ...
  gridBackground.Background = new ImageBrush {
    ImageSource = source,
    Stretch = Stretch.None
  };
}
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagebrush.aspx), ImageBrush inherits from TileBrush. It even says:

> Use for an ImageBrush include decorative effects for text, or tiled
>   backgrounds for controls or layout containers.

I would assume that this should tile the image, if stretching is disabled, but alas, it just draws the image in the middle of the control. I don't see any actual properties to make it tile.

In WPF, there is a [TileMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.tilemode.aspx) property and ViewPort can be set to specify the dimensions of the tile. But this seems absent under the Universal Platform.

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235813/how-to-tile-a-background-image-in-winrt) refers to WinRT (Windows 8), but I'm hoping for a brush based solution, rather than filling a canvas with images.

How do I tile a background image with UWP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A previous question refers to WinRT (Windows 8), but I'm hoping for a brush based solution, rather than filling a canvas with images.

Currently, there are only two solution for showing background image in Tile mode in UWP app, the first one of which you are aware is filling a canvas.

The second one I'm using is to create a Panel and draw the image on it, this idea is derived from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/777534/Tiled-Background-for-Windows-Store-Applications)

*What this method does is that it abuses the fact that we are drawing repeated sets of lines in a rectangular shape. First, it tries to draw a block at the top with the same height as our tile. Then it copies that block down until it reaches the bottom.*

I've modified some code and fix some issues:

```
public class TiledBackground : Panel
{
        public ImageSource BackgroundImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(BackgroundImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackgroundImageProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BackgroundImage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(TiledBackground), new PropertyMetadata(null, BackgroundImageChanged));


        private static void BackgroundImageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((TiledBackground)d).OnBackgroundImageChanged();
        }
        private static void DesignDataChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((TiledBackground)d).OnDesignDataChanged();
        }

        private ImageBrush backgroundImageBrush = null;

        private bool tileImageDataRebuildNeeded = true;
        private byte[] tileImagePixels = null;
        private int tileImageWidth = 0;
        private int tileImageHeight = 0;

        private readonly BitmapPixelFormat bitmapPixelFormat = BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8;
        private readonly BitmapTransform bitmapTransform = new BitmapTransform();
        private readonly BitmapAlphaMode bitmapAlphaMode = BitmapAlphaMode.Straight;
        private readonly ExifOrientationMode exifOrientationMode = ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation;
        private readonly ColorManagementMode coloManagementMode = ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb;

        public TiledBackground()
        {
            this.backgroundImageBrush = new ImageBrush();
            this.Background = backgroundImageBrush;

            this.SizeChanged += TiledBackground_SizeChanged;
        }

        private async void TiledBackground_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            await this.Render((int)e.NewSize.Width, (int)e.NewSize.Height);
        }

        private async void OnBackgroundImageChanged()
        {
            tileImageDataRebuildNeeded = true;
            await Render((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);
        }

        private async void OnDesignDataChanged()
        {
            tileImageDataRebuildNeeded = true;
            await Render((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);
        }

        private async Task RebuildTileImageData()
        {
            BitmapImage image = BackgroundImage as BitmapImage;
            if ((image != null) && (!DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled))
            {
                string imgUri = image.UriSource.OriginalString;
                if (!imgUri.Contains("ms-appx:///"))
                {
                    imgUri += "ms-appx:///";
                }
                var imageSource = new Uri(imgUri);
                StorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(imageSource);
                using (var imageStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);

                    var pixelDataProvider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(this.bitmapPixelFormat, this.bitmapAlphaMode,
                        this.bitmapTransform, this.exifOrientationMode, this.coloManagementMode
                        );

                    this.tileImagePixels = pixelDataProvider.DetachPixelData();
                    this.tileImageHeight = (int)decoder.PixelHeight;
                    this.tileImageWidth = (int)decoder.PixelWidth;
                }
            }
        }

        private byte[] CreateBackgroud(int width, int height)
        {
            int bytesPerPixel = this.tileImagePixels.Length / (this.tileImageWidth * this.tileImageHeight);
            byte[] data = new byte[width * height * bytesPerPixel];

            int y = 0;
            int fullTileInRowCount = width / tileImageWidth;
            int tileRowLength = tileImageWidth * bytesPerPixel;

            //Stage 1: Go line by line and create a block of our pattern
            //Stop when tile image height or required height is reached
            while ((y < height) && (y < tileImageHeight))
            {
                int tileIndex = y * tileImageWidth * bytesPerPixel;
                int dataIndex = y * width * bytesPerPixel;

                //Copy the whole line from tile at once
                for (int i = 0; i < fullTileInRowCount; i++)
                {
                    Array.Copy(tileImagePixels, tileIndex, data, dataIndex, tileRowLength);
                    dataIndex += tileRowLength;
                }

                //Copy the rest - if there is any
                //Length will evaluate to 0 if all lines were copied without remainder
                Array.Copy(tileImagePixels, tileIndex, data, dataIndex,
                           (width - fullTileInRowCount * tileImageWidth) * bytesPerPixel);
                y++; //Next line
            }

            //Stage 2: Now let's copy those whole blocks from top to bottom
            //If there is not enough space to copy the whole block, skip to stage 3
            int rowLength = width * bytesPerPixel;
            int blockLength = this.tileImageHeight * rowLength;

            while (y <= (height - tileImageHeight))
            {
                int dataBaseIndex = y * width * bytesPerPixel;
                Array.Copy(data, 0, data, dataBaseIndex, blockLength);
                y += tileImageHeight;
            }

            //Copy the rest line by line
            //Use previous lines as source
            for (int row = y; row < height; row++)
                Array.Copy(data, (row - tileImageHeight) * rowLength, data, row * rowLength, rowLength);

            return data;
        }

        private async Task Render(int width, int height)
        {
            Stopwatch fullsw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            if (tileImageDataRebuildNeeded)
                await RebuildTileImageData();

            if ((height > 0) && (width > 0))
            {
                using (var randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
                {
                    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    var backgroundPixels = CreateBackgroud(width, height);
                    sw.Stop();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Background generation finished: {0} ticks - {1} ms", sw.ElapsedTicks, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, randomAccessStream);
                    encoder.SetPixelData(this.bitmapPixelFormat, this.bitmapAlphaMode, (uint)width, (uint)height, 96, 96, backgroundPixels);
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();

                    if (this.backgroundImageBrush.ImageSource == null)
                    {
                        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                        randomAccessStream.Seek(0);
                        bitmapImage.SetSource(randomAccessStream);
                        this.backgroundImageBrush.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
                    }
                    else ((BitmapImage)this.backgroundImageBrush.ImageSource).SetSource(randomAccessStream);
                }
            }
            else this.backgroundImageBrush.ImageSource = null;

            fullsw.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine("Background rendering finished: {0} ticks - {1} ms", fullsw.ElapsedTicks, fullsw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <tileCtrl:TiledBackground
                               BackgroundImage="Assets/avatar1.png"
                               Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=rootGrid}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=rootGrid}"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image: Screenshot]

**Check the solution in** [Github](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/TileBackgroundImageUWPApp/TileBackgroundImageUWPApp)

Comment: Nice one Franklin! It seems a bit of a waste of memory to have a specific bitmap just to fill the area, but I've adapted your code to my custom control and it does work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

All these variants are heavy for GPU. You should make it via **Composition** API using **BorderEffect**.

```
        var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;
        var canvasDevice = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
        var graphicsDevice = CanvasComposition.CreateCompositionGraphicsDevice(compositor, canvasDevice);

        var bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(canvasDevice, new Uri("ms-appx:///YourProject/Assets/texture.jpg"));

        var drawingSurface = graphicsDevice.CreateDrawingSurface(bitmap.Size,
            DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, DirectXAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
        using (var ds = CanvasComposition.CreateDrawingSession(drawingSurface))
        {
            ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
            ds.DrawImage(bitmap);
        }

        var surfaceBrush = compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(drawingSurface);
        surfaceBrush.Stretch = CompositionStretch.None;

        var border = new BorderEffect
        {
            ExtendX = CanvasEdgeBehavior.Wrap,
            ExtendY = CanvasEdgeBehavior.Wrap,
            Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("source")
        };

        var fxFactory = compositor.CreateEffectFactory(border);
        var fxBrush = fxFactory.CreateBrush();
        fxBrush.SetSourceParameter("source", surfaceBrush);

        var sprite = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        sprite.Size = new Vector2(1000000);
        sprite.Brush = fxBrush;

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(YourCanvas, sprite);
```

I tried 1000000x1000000 size sprite and it worked with no efforts.

**Win2d** will throw you an exception if your size is bigger than 16386px.

Comment: how i can do this for Text ( string) instead of Image? i want to make a watermark (repeat text)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it is now possible to create a custom brush (with help of Composition API and Win2D) to achieve the tiling effect. Code sample here: [UWP TiledBrush](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1236452/UWP-TiledBrush)

In short, you just subclass the `XamlCompositionBrushBase` and override it's `OnConnected` method:

```
public class TiledBrush : XamlCompositionBrushBase
{
  protected override void OnConnected()
  {
    var surface = LoadedImageSurface.StartLoadFromUri(ImageSourceUri);

    var surfaceBrush = Compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(surface);

    surfaceBrush.Stretch = CompositionStretch.None;

    var borderEffect = new BorderEffect()
    {
        Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("source"),
        ExtendX = Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasEdgeBehavior.Wrap,
        ExtendY = Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasEdgeBehavior.Wrap
    };

    var borderEffectFactory = Compositor.CreateEffectFactory(borderEffect);

    var borderEffectBrush = borderEffectFactory.CreateBrush();

    borderEffectBrush.SetSourceParameter("source", surfaceBrush);
  }
}
```

And then use it as expected:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <local:TiledBrush ImageSourceUri="Assets/Texture.jpg" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Nice work, very simple.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35578113/3968276):

> You can tile using the [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) library. They have [sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-samples%20%22Win2D) as well; there's a tiling sample under "effects" (`EffectsSample.xaml.cs`).

Comment: Here is a sample project implementing the Win2D solution: https://github.com/r2d2rigo/Win2D-Samples/tree/master/TiledBackground

Answer (score 0):

We have the [`TilesBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/brushes/tilesbrush) in the Windows Community Toolkit:

```xml
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="400" Height="400">
  <Border.Background>
    <brushes:TilesBrush TextureUri="ms-appx:///Assets/BrushAssets/TileTexture.png"/>
  </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

We also have the [`TileControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/tilecontrol) which allows for animations.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting that when using Win2d from C# one must watch out for tmemory leakage. Also there are some subtleties if you want to dynamically change the bitmap resource.

See the answer to this question for one solution to those points: [Repeating brush or tile of image in WinUI 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74527783/repeating-brush-or-tile-of-image-in-winui-3)

Answer (score 0):

The "Border" example in the WindowsCompositorSamples also shows how to do this, with rotation and scaling as well.

Link: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2015063/BorderPlayground