# How to fill a Win10 XAML Polygon with tiles?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am trying to make XAML Polygon filled with a transformed texture. The code worked well in WPF but in a Windows 10 app there seems to be no TileMode property.

```
 <Polygon Points="300,200 400,125 400,275" Stroke="Purple" StrokeThickness="2">
        <Polygon.Fill>
            <ImageBrush TileMode="Tile" ImageSource="Assets/StoreLogo.png">
                <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" ScaleX="0.2" ScaleY="0.2"/>
                        <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                        <RotateTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" Angle="61.928"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </ImageBrush>
        </Polygon.Fill>
    </Polygon>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35497681/442444

Comment: Well that's a bummer... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can tile using the [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) library. They have [sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-samples%20%22Win2D) as well; there's a tiling sample under "effects" (`EffectsSample.xaml.cs`).