# UWP same SolidColorBrush is different on PC and Mobile

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have next app.xaml resource:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ApplicationBackground" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="3,3" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
      <GradientStop Color="#F1F1F1" Offset="0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#F1F1F1" Offset="0.2"/>
      <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.2"/>
      <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuBackground" Color="#FF01579B"/>
```

I have created a UserControl, that will be as menu content - MenuController.xaml

Here is the code:

```
<UserControl
    <ScrollViewer Background="{StaticResource MenuBackground}">
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

And here i placed it on MainPage:

```
<Page
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationBackground}">
        <controllers:MenuController/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And here how it looks on mobile vs PC:

**Why? What causes this difference and how to fix this?**

[image]

Here is more easy scenario of this behavior:

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ParentBackground" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="3,3" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
        <GradientStop Color="#F1F1F1" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#F1F1F1" Offset="0.2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ChildBackground" Color="White"/>
```

And on MainPage i have 2 grids:

```
<Grid Opacity="1" Background="{StaticResource ParentBackground}">
    <Grid Opacity="1" Canvas.ZIndex="10" Background="{StaticResource ChildBackground}">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**And the inner grid is gray, not white!** **On mobile all is OK**

Comment: MenuBackground != ApplicationBackground, are your sample code snippets correct?

Comment: @Bart Didn't understamnd your question... What here is incorrect? I Have a Single Page application - i can call my resource for main Grid as Applicationbackground

Comment: @Bart And i found the cause og this. On PC LinearGradientBrush seems to be always on top of UI

Answer (score 2):

I was experimenting with this, and it's quite bizarre. It appears to be a bug on desktop, so everything in my answer here applies to desktop only; it works correctly on mobile.

**TL;DR**: The LinearGradientBrush with `SpreadMethod="Repeat"` is causing the inner UserControl to render 50% darker for some reason.

I narrowed it down to the following XAML (a simplification of yours):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush SpreadMethod="Repeat">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Margin="50"/>
</Grid>
```

where the Grid is the Content of the main Page. This is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

The Rectangle should have a white fill but it is gray? This is similar to your XAML because you have a UserControl with a blue background inside a Grid with a linear gradient background.

Notice also the 1px white border rendering artifact on the right and bottom edges of the Rectangle?

The Rectangle will render correctly in any of these situations:

- The Grid has a nonzero margin or a translate RenderTransform.
- The Rectangle has Opacity less than 1.
- The LinearGradientBrush's SpreadMethod is anything but Repeat.
- Probably more...

I've found that the easiest way to correct the problem is to set the opacity of the Rectangle (i.e. your UserControl) to 0.99999:

[image: Screenshot]

but this means the GPU now needs to composite the Rectangle with unnecessary alpha blending, which isn't ideal. My example would benefit by setting the SpreadMethod of the LinearGradientBrush to something else instead (since it appears that's what's causing the problem), but you need it set to Repeat, and it looks like UWP [doesn't support tiled background images out-of-the-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456324/uwp-how-to-tile-a-background-image).

Comment: Intriguing! I have reported this bug in Windows Feedback - feedback-hub:?contextid=381&feedbackid=a7be1e67-cde2-46aa-9504-7e396c9a5c99&form=1&src=2

Comment: Still, though, why would anyone use `SpreadMethod="Repeat"`? I cannot see a justifiable reason to do so. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @IInspectable MZetko needs it in order to generate a repeating background of diagonal lines. Is there a better way of generating a tiled background?

Comment: I suppose I'd draw horizontal/vertical lines and apply a rotation matrix. Although I don't know, if this can be done in XAML. I guess you could create a brush, too, if you needed the tiling. Anyway, do you have more information on what MZetko/Martin Zikmund does (the feedback hub issue doesn't go into much detail).