# Image as background pattern or tiling - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I've been developing wpf apps for a few years, and i used to use the following code to tile an image an use it as a background pattern:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/GroupPattern.png"  TileMode="Tile" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,32,32"/>
```

However, tiling does not seem to work in UWP, after some researching i did not find anything.

So, does anybody what would be the equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP - How to tile a background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456324/uwp-how-to-tile-a-background-image)

Comment: There is not a built in equivalent. If you want to use it as a brush, you'll have to create your own brush from XamlCompositionBrushBase and combine it with Win2D's BorderEffect that enables tiling.

There's an undocumented example of that [here](https://github.com/JohnnyWestlake/LoadedImageSourceBug/tree/master/LoadedImageSurfaceBugRepro/Brushes) but it's not production worthy code (I was using it to report a bug)

Comment: I will give it a try, i don't know why such basic feature is not available...thank you

Comment: I tried and its working, however the tiling is too big, my control its almost the entire page, is there any way to set it to 24x24?

Comment: If this is what you were using the Viewport for, there's not a simple way to do it. (Technically a Win2D CropEffect could usually be chained in to the effect graph to do the job BUT it doesn't work with Composition API's). You can either scale the surface used for the brush with composition API's or create  your own CompositionDrawingSurface and use Win2D API's to draw whatever you want on it. It's certainly not trivial!

Easiest way would be to actually resize the source image though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JohnnyWestlake notised, you could use Microsoft Win2D library. Just add this code snippet to you xaml:

```
<Page .....
     xmlns:win2d="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
      .....>

  <Grid>
    <win2d:CanvasControl CreateResources="BackgroundCanvas_CreateResources" 
                         Draw="BackgroundCanvas_Draw" />
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

and in the .xaml.cs file as follows:

```
    using Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas;
    using Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Brushes;
    using Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI;
    using Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml;
    .......

    private CanvasBitmap backgroundImage;
    private CanvasImageBrush backgroundBrush;

    private void BackgroundCanvas_CreateResources(CanvasControl sender, CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
    {
        args.TrackAsyncAction(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            string uri = "ms-appx:///Assets/Images/GroupPattern.png";

            backgroundImage = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, new Uri(uri));
            backgroundBrush = new CanvasImageBrush(sender, backgroundImage);

            // Set the brush's edge behaviour to wrap, so the image repeats if the drawn region is too big
            backgroundBrush.ExtendX = backgroundBrush.ExtendY = CanvasEdgeBehavior.Wrap;
            backgroundBrush.Transform = System.Numerics.Matrix3x2.CreateScale(0.5f);
        }).AsAsyncAction());
    }

    private void BackgroundCanvas_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        var session = args.DrawingSession;
        session.FillRectangle(new Rect(new Point(), sender.RenderSize), backgroundBrush);
    }
```

Hope it helps)