# Windows Store App TileMode in ImageBrush is missing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I read this link [How to TILE a background image in WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235813/how-to-tile-a-background-image-in-winrt)

I need to have a background image for example 300*1000 pixel i have base image in 300*10 pixel and i want to repeat this base image for the background
i use this line and really TileMode is not in this version of Metro/XAML.

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Note.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentY="Top" x:Name="my_image" >
```

i want to have to repeat "my_image" for 100times!

have can i do that? is there any idea?

thnak for your attention

Comment: "is there any idea?" Sure, use your favorite image manipulation tool and create the desired 300*1000 pixel image by copy&pasting the source image a hundred times.

Comment: Could try one of the [alternatives](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/777534/Tiled-Background-for-Windows-Store-Applications) though I have no experience with any of them.

Comment: @Clemens i did that but my technical manager say me to correct that in source code ,in her opinion this work is NOT optimize!!

Comment: @ChrisW. i saw that link i cant use this because i used ImageBrush in background property.

Comment: @nik Does your "technical manager" have a better solution? You should probably ask her for constructive feedback. Anyway, having one large bitmap with a background pattern is *a lot* better in terms of performance and code complexity than creating a Grid of Image controls.